# AWS RDS Aurora MySQL 5.7 instances crashing randomly without reason in rds events, how to debug further?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have observed that RDS aurora mysql instances in our aws account getting crashed, There was no reason for crash in logs and rds events.

Recently it happened for r5.large instance, Please find attached screenshot.

There was nothing logs of rds instance.

How can we get the reason why it was crashed? so that we can check it further.

How should we debug such issues?

[image]